# Responsive navbar in UIKit 3?

Tags: javascript, css, getuikit

I've been migrating my website over to UIkit 3 instead of Bootstrap 4. But I've been stuck on the navbar for a while. Right now, my navbar is built in Bootstrap 4 and looks like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/eztwL9p7/1/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm  sticky-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <a class="navbar-brand">brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Blog <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <auth-partial>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item float-xs-right">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Log in</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </auth-partial>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So it's just a normal navbar, but when the page is small enough, a toggle button appears and the items become a drop down list. I've been trying to migrate this to UIKit, but I don't see any option for this in their templates. If I understand it right, it seems like I have to make 2 navbars, one for the normal view and then a smaller one?

The [Navbar documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/navbar#toggle-item) suggests that the `.uk-navbar-toggle` class and the `.uk-navbar-toggle-icon` are added like below - resulting in a toggle icon - but without an expandable menu and also not able to hide specified menu items as Bootstrap can do.

```
<nav class="uk-navbar uk-navbar-container uk-margin">
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">
        <a class="uk-navbar-toggle" uk-navbar-toggle-icon href="#"></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The [Navbar documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/navbar#toggle-item) recommends that the [Off-canvas component](https://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas) (sidebar that slides in and out of the page) - or the [Modal component](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal) - but neither of these result in a Bootstrap-style toggle menu.

Screenshots that show how the responsive navbar toggle / hide specified elements on smaller screens in Bootstrap:

**Screen in normal size - all menu items are shown:**
[image]

**Screen in smaller size - some or all menu items are hidden:**
[image]

**Screen in smaller size - pressing Menu displays menu items:**
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I found no solution except to create 2 navbars, and making only one visible depending on the width

Comment: As you though, it appears that UIkit expects the implementation with duplicated navbars similar as on their website. This is not always a good idea and I am strongly against such workarounds. For me it just looks as an unnecessary way of making the menu less maintainable, more error-prone and not to mention duplicated content might have negative impact on SEO. This is one of the biggest disappointments that I ran into while discovering this great framework which really does have a lot of potential. Not having an out-of-the-box togglable and stackable navbar is a big NO, NO Sorry UIkit dev team

Answer (score 3):

It's obvious UIkit expects the implementation with duplicated navbars each visible only in the respective viewport. That's their own website solution. In my opinion it is not always a good idea. I am strongly against such workarounds because to me it looks like an unnecessary way of making the menu less maintainable, less accessible, less structured, less readable or machine-parsable, more error-prone and not to mention duplicated content might have negative impact on SEO. It was one of the biggest disappointments that I ran into while discovering this great framework which really does have a lot of potential. Not having an out-of-the-box togglable and stackable navbar is a big NO, NO - sorry UIkit dev team. Other than that UIkit is an awesome toolkit.

If one wants to use a modal or off-canvas solutions as per their recommendation feel free to do so. But in that case I would still recommend not to have duplicated content on your site. Maybe one could use Javascript to move the content dynamically instead.

I am personally in favor of bootstrap-like navbar solution without a need of duplicated content. It is currently used on many major websites around. So why not to support it?

**Requirements:**

- Horizontal navbar to be stackable vertically in smartphone view
- Toggle navbar 'hidden' and 'hamburger icon' shown when reached smartphone view
- Toggle icon shows/hides the navbar in smartphone view
- Navbar is never hidden in desktop view, no matter if toggle icon was used or not

**Solution:**

Yes it's ugly, I know...

```
<nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-flex-column uk-flex-top" data-uk-navbar data-uk-toggle="media: @s; cls: uk-flex-row uk-flex-top; mode: media">
    <button type="button" data-uk-toggle="target: .navbar-collapse; cls: hidden-up-to-s" class="uk-navbar-toggle uk-hidden@s" data-uk-navbar-toggle-icon></button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse hidden-up-to-s">
        <div class="uk-navbar-left">
            <ul data-uk-toggle="media: @s; cls: uk-navbar-nav uk-padding-remove; mode: media" class="uk-nav uk-nav-primary uk-padding-small">
                <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And some custom CSS in order to have the navbar hidden only in smartphone view:

```
.hidden-up-to-s {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) { /* @breakpoint-small */
    .hidden-up-to-s {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

More examples here:
https://codepen.io/Hrvoje-Go/pen/LKWojr

Comment: Don't remember what was the problem with the posted solution but in the end I wrote JS script which places the menu where it needs to be structurally depending on the viewport

Comment: This worked nicely for normal usage, but it kinda breaks in the dropbar mode with parent navigation items.

Answer (score 1):

Late Answer... With some CSS you can modify UiKit's Navbar to work like Bootstrap's responsive Navbar.
Please note that this sample is not styled to look beautiful - I tried to keep the CSS as short as possible.

On mobile devices (touch) the drop-downs will open/close on touch event (this is an out-of-the-box feature of UiKit).

```css
.uk-navbar {
  min-height: 50px;
}
.uk-navbar button.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.uk-navbar button.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #888;
}
.uk-navbar button.navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.uk-navbar .uk-navbar-nav {
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.uk-navbar .uk-navbar-nav > li > a {
  min-height: auto;
  line-height: 3em;
}
@media (max-width: 959px) {
  .uk-navbar .toggle-target.collapsed {
    display: none;
  }
  .uk-navbar .toggle-target .uk-navbar-nav {
    display: block;
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f8f8f8;
  }
  .uk-navbar .toggle-target .uk-navbar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    min-height: 0;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 15px !important;
  }
  .uk-navbar .toggle-target .uk-navbar-dropdown {
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 200px;
  }
  .uk-navbar .toggle-target .uk-navbar-dropdown[class*='uk-navbar-dropdown-bottom'] {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
a#logo {
  align-items:baseline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.3/js/uikit-core.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.3/css/uikit-core.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <section id="mainnav">
        <nav class="uk-container" uk-navbar>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle uk-hidden@m" uk-toggle="target:.toggle-target; cls:collapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="uk-navbar-brand">
                <a href="/" id="logo" class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo">LOGO</a>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-navbar-right toggle-target collapsed">
                <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Company</a>
                        <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
                            <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">About Us </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Quality & Environment</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                        <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
                            <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Carriere</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <nav class="uk-navbar uk-navbar-container uk-margin  uk-hidden@m">
        <div class="uk-navbar-left">
            <a class="uk-navbar-toggle" uk-navbar-toggle-icon href="#" uk-toggle="target: #offcanvas-nav"></a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="offcanvas-nav" uk-offcanvas="overlay: false">
        <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar   uk-hidden@m">

            <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default">
                <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                <li class="uk-parent">
                    <a href="#">Parent</a>
                    <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="uk-nav-header">Header</li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: table"></span> Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: thumbnails"></span> Item</a></li>
                <li class="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: trash"></span> Item</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```